# Hide script tag in markdown on Github

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have this script tag in a markdown file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&lang=java"></script>
```

I don't want it to display in the markdown, but it shows up like this:

[image]

Is there a way to hide the script tag so it doesn't display on Github?

Comment: Can you just remove it? GitHub won't include / run scripts for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide content in markdown using HTML syntax:

```
<!-- Insert your script here and it won’t show up. -->
```

Comment: Note that it won’t render on GitHub. But this will work.